# Geodesics and Christoffel symbols

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

If these are satisfied then we are on a geodesic. Do I just need to plug in the condition given about the christoffel symbols and then see that the equations are allways fulfiled as long as $v=at+b$ and $u=ct+d$ i.e. some straight line in the $(u,v)$-plan (down in the map)

Comment: What is the metric? You need to give a bit more information about the question before it is answerable.